# Source Reader ReadSample(), IMFSourceReaderCallback::OnReadSample() memory leak?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

First, execute

```
hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
     (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
     0,
     NULL,   // actual
     NULL,   // flags
     NULL,   // timestamp
     NULL    // sample
     );
```

Then, at the beginning of the following, the memory used by this process adds about 3M:

```
HRESULT CCapture::OnReadSample(
     HRESULT hrStatus,
     DWORD /*dwStreamIndex*/,
     DWORD /*dwStreamFlags*/,
     LONGLONG llTimeStamp,
     IMFSample *pSample      // Can be NULL
     )
{
     .....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the source reader creation method, but from your `ReadSample` code it seems like you work in the asynchronous mode (as all the parameters except for `dwStreamIndex` are NULL). Therefore, when `OnReadSample` callback is called, you get the ready frame - which takes 3 MB of the memory. So it looks like the expected behavior.
See the remarks section of `ReadSample` function in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374665(v=vs.85).aspx).